# PHP - Strange thing with simple preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this array:

```
'@(.*?)<div>(.*?)</div>(.*?)@i' => 'ok'
```

And I am using preg_replace to return the value "ok" from some string.

The problem is that when I do the preg_replace, the last   `(.*?)` isn't "detected".

**Example**

I have the string: `test1<div>test2</div>test3`

And with that array and preg_replace, it would return `oktest3`. Why isn't test3 replaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that `.*?` is a non-greedy match, and thus tries to match as little as possible.

If you want it to match from the beginning and to the end of the string, use a [`^` and `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to anchor the regex to the beginning and end, like so:

```
'@^(.*?)<div>(.*?)</div>(.*?)$@i' => 'ok'
```

Comment: @AfonsoMatos: Happy to help. Remember to accept my answer, if you feel it solves your problem. I can recommend checking out http://regular-expressions.info - it's a pretty good source of information.

Comment: Ok, thx for the website. I didn't accept it yet, because I get some error telling me to try in 6 minutes..